# The trial period for this product has expired Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I was not able to log into the website configured in Sharepoint 2010 due to this error message.

> "The trial period for this product has expired"

The log shows that:

> Exception thrown while adding control
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls.SearchBoxEx'
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.dll

I wasn't able to access any pages in the website other than the site settings page.

I am using Sharepoint Enterprise edition. Please help me to remove this error and to continue the work

Comment: You can find the dll from "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\ISAPI"

Comment: The fix come by uninstalling a feature, so  @skeletank how can you say it is off topic?

Comment: That's a built-in feature and not one that you developed/need programming help with.  What programming is involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft.sharepoint.portal.dll is used in two features of Sharepoint, they are OSearchBasicFeature and OSearchEnhancedFeature. To fix this issue if you are not using the Search feature you can uninstall these features by

> stsadm -o uninstallfeature -name OSearchBasicFeature -force
>
> stsadm -o uninstallfeature -name OSearchEnhancedFeature-force

This will fix the issue :)

Answer (score -1):

Just run the SharePoint 2010 Products Configuration Wizard again. It will solve the error in most of cases.

Other possible causes are AntiVirus program updates or some service pack installation.

Sometime even if Central Administration site’s application pool is running under Network Service account instead of the farm administrator account cause this. In that case just change the application pool identity to the Farm administrator account.  You can do this either through the Service Accounts  section of Central Admin or through the IIS.

Answer (score -2):

Have you recently applied a service pack to your SharePoint site. I remember this issue happening before when Microsoft released SP1.

Please check the "Manage servers in this farm" (/_admin/FarmServers.aspx) and see if there are pending updates to be applied.

Also
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointadmin/thread/08bdfc4d-f83f-4a74-b53e-b70d91047015

> I know its a bit late now however this seems to be an incorrect error
>   message being thrown.
>
> To resolve simply run stsadm -o activatefeature -name
>   PublishingResources -url http://

Comment: Error with Microsoft.Office.Server.dll and not with Publishing Resource